# JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in POST request

Tags: python, json, django

I'm working on a project where I integrated a payment gateway, where I created a JSON string and pass URL, when all information is correct, then it generates a payment link. When I used demo URL and demo data it worked perfectly but when I use real URL it says this error.
here is view.py:

```
def payment(request):
    jsonObj={
        "name": "name"
    }
    json_string = json.dumps(jsonObj)
    print(json_string)
    url = "https://url.something"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 
    'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())
    j = r.json()['status']
    k = r.json()['data']
            if j == "200":
        payment_id = k['payment_id']
        redirect_url = k['redirect_url']
        payment_link = str(redirect_url) + "?" + str(payment_id)
        print(payment_link)
        context = {
            'payment_link': payment_link,
        }
        return render(request, 'users_dashboard/payment.html', context)
return render(request, 'users_dashboard/product_rashid.html')
```

Comment: `r.json()` might cause the error if the response is not valid json. Try printing the response text before that.

Comment: I removed print(r.json()) line, but still the same error

Comment: You are calling `r.json()` anyway..... What I said was try printing the response **text** / **content** **before** any call to `r.json`

Comment: I'm a beginner can you please write it, please

Comment: `print(r.text)` you will still get error but before that the response text would be printed. Is it valid json? It may give you a clue where you went wrong.

Comment: I printed r.text and it looks like:
`<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code in this manner:

```
def payment(request):
    url = "https://url.something"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.47.1'}
    jsonObj={
        "name": "name"
    }
    post = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(jsonObj), headers=headers)
    print(post.status_code, post.reason)

    j = post.json()['status']
    k = post.json()['data']
    if j == "200":
        payment_id = k['payment_id']
        redirect_url = k['redirect_url']
        payment_link = str(redirect_url) + "?" + str(payment_id)
        print(payment_link)
        context = {
            'payment_link': payment_link,
        }
        return render(request, 'users_dashboard/payment.html', context)
return render(request, 'users_dashboard/product_rashid.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

1st thing response from API is not always JSON, so you need to handle this condition.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json_string, headers=headers)
print(type(r))  # check the type
try:
   print(r.json())
   j = r.json()['status']
   k = r.json()['data']
            if j == "200":
        payment_id = k['payment_id']
        redirect_url = k['redirect_url']
        payment_link = str(redirect_url) + "?" + str(payment_id)
        print(payment_link)
        context = {
            'payment_link': payment_link,
        }
except:
    context = {}
```

Comment: payment_link is empty, pass to except case. not in try